# Remove Set interval on component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code for notification fetching

```
 static contextType = Context;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roleName: null,
      notCount : null,
      notificationData:[],
      gotoNotify:false,
    }
  }

  logOut = () => {
    Cookies.remove('_token');
    Cookies.remove('_ACid');
    Cookies.remove('_ACrole');
    Cookies.remove('_ACname');
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNotification();
     setInterval(() => {
    this.getNotification();
  }, 10000);
  }
 
  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval();
    console.log("yes")
  }
```

I want to clearinterval when this component will unmount or when logout please help me to do this

Comment: Assign the interval identifier to state and pass it in when you call `clearInterval`?

Comment: Just store the interval id.. `this.intervalId = setInterval(`, and then you can clear it -> `clearInterval(this.invervalId)`

Comment: @DBS I wouldn't use state, or your going to get a pointless re-render.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the interval identifier and use it to clear it:

```js
consructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {...}
  
  this.notificationInterval = null; // unnecessary but good to keep track of it
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getNotification();
  this.notificationInterval = setInterval(this.getNotification, 10000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.notificationInterval);
}
```

As a small note, you can call `setInterval(fn)` directly without using the arrow function:

```js
// The two calls are pretty much equal:

setInterval(() => this.getNotification(), 1000);
setInterval(this.getNotification, 10000);
```

Comment: The 'without arrow function' version is fine if the given function doesn't use `this`. If it does, however, it can cause problems, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/8376184)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable to assign your interval id.

After, you can clear your interval with this id

```js
static contextType = Context;
let intervalId;
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    roleName: null,
    notCount: null,
    notificationData: [],
    gotoNotify: false,
  }
}

logOut = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  Cookies.remove('_token');
  Cookies.remove('_ACid');
  Cookies.remove('_ACrole');
  Cookies.remove('_ACname');
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.getNotification();
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    this.getNotification();
  }, 10000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  console.log("yes")
}
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to use a global variable, think of the case where a component is called multiple times. All the variables would point to the same global instance. It's better for it to be part of the Class / Object by using `this.property`.

Comment: Yes like that you don't create several interval to notify the user. That why I use global variable.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In that case makes sense indeed 